# How Set Manage Stock as no in the magento - Programmatically

Tags: product, inventory

How Set `Manage Stock` as `no` in the magento, 
i have used this code but manage stock showing as yes

```
            $_product->setStockData(array( 
                'manage_stock' => 0,
                'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 0
            ));
```

but when use

```
            $_product->setStockData(array( 
                'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                'qty' => 9999,
                'manage_stock' => 0,
                'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 0
            ));
```

the quantity and is_in_stock status has been update but manage stock not setting as no.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check your value for `use_config_manage_stock`, it could be defaulting to that default value, so you'll want to set `use_config_manage_stock` to 0 as well as `manage_stock` to 0 too, depending on your settings.

```
$_product->setStockData(array( 
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
            'is_in_stock' => 1, 
            'qty' => 9999,
            'manage_stock' => 0,
            'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 0
        )); 
$_product->save();
```

Comment: Great to know Helphin, would ya mind clicking the tick mark to accept it as an answer if it's helping you? :)

Comment: its done, just waited for required time, once again thanks