# Why have my configurables stock status Out of Stock

Tags: magento2.2, configurable-product, stock

All I found so far is from the [User Guide](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html) in Step 4 under 2.:

> The Quantity is determined by the product variations, so you can leave it blank for now.
>
> The Stock Status of a configurable product is determined by each associated configuration. Because the product was saved without entering a quantity, the Stock Status is now set to “Out of Stock.”

According to this the **Quantity** is determined by the product variations but how about the **Stock Status**? If you have variations that are "In Stock" shouldn't be the configurable "In Stock" too?

**My background:**
Our products are created via rest api like this:

1. All simples
2. The configurables with the simple ids that belong to them in `configurable_product_links`

In our case all configurables are set to "Out of Stock". Even when I reindex the **Stock Status** is not getting updated. Is this expected behavior?

**I've already tried:**

- Clearing cache
- Reindexing

Here an example json we post to create a configurable:

```
{
  "product": {
    "typeId": "configurable",
    "sku": "sku",
    "status": 1,
    "attributeSetId": 44,
    "name": "Configurable product name",
    "extensionAttributes": {
      "configurable_product_options": [
        {
          "attribute_id": 861,
          "label": "Some Label",
          "values": [
            {
              "value_index": 15929
            },
            {
              "value_index": 15945
            },
            {
              "value_index": 15967
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "configurable_product_links": [
        18449,
        18450,
        18451
      ],
      "category_links": [
        {
          "position": 0,
          "category_id": 899
        }
      ]
    },
    "customAttributes": [
      {
        "attributeCode": "description",
        "value": "Our description"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check child products? they are on stock? 18449,18450,18451 ???

Comment: for them Manage Stock is disabled could that be the reason?

Comment: of course yes, because configurable products don`t show individually, they are depends on child products stocks

Comment: makes sense I didn't take that into account

Comment: do it, it will help you , I`ll be happy!

Comment: I just verified that if I create the configurable with `manage_stock=false` it works as expected. @alexeyboltynov do you want to write an answer or shall I summarize it as an answer?

Comment: i will ad answer thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the configurable product with manage_stock=false it will works as expected!

Comment: This works indeed. I just think that this is a little inconsistent from Magento because if the Manage Stock is false it doesn't mean it is Out of Stock especially when the variants have a Quantity >0

Comment: Can you describe how you added the parameters manage_stock=false to the payload? I can not find the documentation.

Comment: @Azngeek https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14903/how-set-manage-stock-as-no-in-the-magento-programmatically

Comment: I mean to the API-Payload. However i found it.

Answer (score -1):

***1) Pass 2 params in headers:***

a) Content-Type:application/json
b) Authorization: Bearer {token}

***2) Create the simple product ============= Payload ==== POST Method = /rest/default/V1/products***

{
"product": {
"sku": "tester-rj-sm",
"name": "Tester Rj Small",
"attribute_set_id": 4,
"price": 25,
"status": 1,
"visibility": 1,
"type_id": "simple",
"weight": "0.5",
"extension_attributes": {
"stock_item": {
"qty": "10",
"is_in_stock": true
}
},
"custom_attributes": [
{
"attribute_code": "description",
"value": "Long description......."
},
{
"attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
"value": "2"
},
{
"attribute_code": "size",
"value": "507"
}
]
}
}

***3) Create the configurable product ============= Payload ==== POST Method = /rest/default/V1/products***

{
"product": {
"sku": "tester-rj1",
"name": "Tester Rj",
"attribute_set_id": 4,
"status": 1,
"visibility": 4,
"type_id": "configurable",
"weight": "0.5",
"extension_attributes": { "stock_item": {"itemId":null,"productId":0,"stockId":1,"qty":0,"isInStock":true,"isQtyDecimal":true,"showDefaultNotificationMessage":false, "useConfigMinQty":true,"minQty":1,"useConfigMinSaleQty":1,"minSaleQty":1,"useConfigMaxSaleQty":false,"maxSaleQty":0,"useConfigBackorders":true, "backorders":0,"useConfigNotifyStockQty":true,"notifyStockQty":1,"useConfigQtyIncrements":true,"qtyIncrements":1,"useConfigEnableQtyInc":true,"enableQtyIncrements":true,"useConfigManageStock":true,"manageStock":true, "lowStockDate":null,"isDecimalDivided":true,"stockStatusChangedAuto":0,"extensionAttributes":null} },
"custom_attributes": [
{
"attribute_code": "description",
"value": "Long description....."
},
{
"attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
"value": "2"
}
]
}
}

***4) Define configurable product options ======= Payload ====== POST Method = /rest/default/V1/configurable-products/tester-rj1/options***

{
"option": {
"attribute_id": "180",
"label": "Size",
"position": 0,
"is_use_default": true,
"values": [
{
"value_index": 507
}
]
}
}

***5) Link the simple products to the configurable product === Payload ==== POST Method = /rest/default/V1/configurable-products/tester-rj1/child***

{
"childSku": "tester-rj-sm"
}

**Above are the steps to create configurable product using Magento 2.X.X rest API. This way configurable product will be In Stock and will be available for purchase automatically.**